# Webpack es2015 tree shaking with React

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

I would like to use tree shaking feature seems we don't need to install `babel-preset-es2015-webpack`. We still can use `babel-preset-es2015` and set the modules flag to false for `es2015` preset. I changed my webpack configuration as shown below which results in "Unexpected token import" error on import line in my react components.

```
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          presets: [['es2015', {modules: false}], 'react']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader!sass-loader")
      }
    ]
  }
```

I also tried to set the presets as

```
['es2015', 'react', {modules: false}]
```

Then I got different error on console:

```
 Module build failed: ReferenceError: [BABEL] C:\FE-Proj-Templates\webpack\main.js: Using removed Babel 5 option: foreign.modules - Use the corresponding module transform plugin in the `plugins` option. Check out http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/#modules
```

How can I set the preset `es2015` with modules flag false and also use React preset?

Comment: Are you using webpack 2 (beta)? Webpack 1 does not support ES2015 modules (and tree shaking).

Comment: Yes I'm using webpack 2

Comment: @NeginBasiri Did you find a solution?

Comment: @GuilhermeMattarBastos Not yet. I commented on https://egghead.io/forums/lesson-discussion/topics/tree-shaking-with-webpack-2?page=1 as well (Not sure if you can see discussions). I'll update  this ticket when I get it work.

Answer (score 12):

It's updated and works

```
presets: [['es2015', {modules: false}], 'react']
```

Comment: It's important to note that `['es2015', {modules: false}]` is in a separate array. I overlooked it at first.

Comment: you can optimise it a little more with adding `loose: true` like so `presets: [['es2015', {loose: true, modules: false}], 'react']`